# Javascript fetch api return 200 and response but .then cant work

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, openweathermap

I am trying the openweathermap API on web. The fetch is indeed return 200 ok and responses but the following `.then` seems to not work or inherited from fetch as I cant manipulate the received data either in `console.log`, alert or print to html.

It doesn't show any error or warnings. But just:

> [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 637ms].

Please help me on my code. Very much appreciated.

```js
let weatherInfo = document.getElementById("weatherInfo");

//Trigger on click on HTML 
function submitFormCheck() {

  //Check if text field contain value
  //Check if browser support Geolocation
  const txtBox = document.getElementById('textBoxx').value;
  if (txtBox == "" || txtBox.length == 0 || txtBox == null) {
    //Retrieve the location from callback and fetch api
    getLocation(function(lat_lng) {
      console.log(`longitude: ${ lat_lng.lat } | latitude: ${ lat_lng.lng }`);
      const url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=' + lat_lng.lat + '&lon=' + lat_lng.lng + '&APPID=075bd82caf51b82c26d704147ba475da&units=metric';
      const fetchDetails = {
        method: 'GET'
      };

      fetch(url, fetchDetails)
        .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then((data) => {
          console.log("testing"); //console.log cant work 
          alert("testing"); //alert cant work
          let i = data.city;
          console.log(i.name); // response.data cant print out
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    });


  } else {
    return false;
  }

  
  function getLocation(callback) {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {

      let lat_lng = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        // get current location by using html 5 geolocation api
        let userPosition = {};
        userPosition.lat = position.coords.latitude;
        userPosition.lng = position.coords.longitude;
        callback(userPosition);

      }, positionHandlingError);
    } else {
      alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser. Please enter the location manually");
    }
  }



  // if failed to get location
  function positionHandlingError(error) {
    switch (error.code) {
      case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
        console.log("User denied the request for Geolocation.");
        break;
      case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
        console.log("Location information is unavailable.");
        break;
      case error.TIMEOUT:
        console.log("The request to get user location timed out.");
        break;
      case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
        console.log("An unknown error occurred.");
        break;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Is there any console error output?

Comment: Nop. It doesnt show any error or warnings.Also getting [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 637ms]

Comment: You are lacking an [mcve] but I'm betting, giving the name `submitFormCheck`, that you click a submit button, start the JavaScript running, then the browser navigates to the response to the form submission before the Ajax response has been received. Since the page hosting the JS is no longer loaded, it never runs the response handler.

Comment: Thank you guys. I modified some code and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you didn't prevent the default behaviour of form submitting:

```
function submitFormCheck(e) {

  //Prevent form submit
  e.preventDefault();

  //Check if text field contain value
  //Check if browser support Geolocation
  const txtBox = document.getElementById('textBoxx').value;

  ...
```

Comment: I followed your suggestion and modified some codes and it works. Thank you so much